# python mysqldb import error

Tags: python, ubuntu, mysql-python

on ubuntu i have installed mysql but still i cannot import mysql database. Below are the steps that i followed.Can any one point me to a solution to this
(Other info is ubuntu is installed on a virtual box hope that should not matter).Python version is 2.6.5

```
  root@rajeev-laptop:/opt/s/site# apt-get install python-mysqldb
  Reading package lists... Done
  Building dependency tree
  Reading state information... Done
  The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
    linux-headers-2.6.32-21 linux-headers-2.6.32-21-generic
  Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
  Suggested packages:
    python-mysqldb-dbg
  The following NEW packages will be installed:
    python-mysqldb
  0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
  Need to get 0B/76.6kB of archives.
  After this operation, 283kB of additional disk space will be used.
  Selecting previously deselected package python-mysqldb.
  (Reading database ... 151280 files and directories currently installed.)
  Unpacking python-mysqldb (from .../python-mysqldb_1.2.2-10build1_i386.deb) ...
  Setting up python-mysqldb (1.2.2-10build1) ...

  Processing triggers for python-support ...
  root@rajeev-laptop:/opt/s/site# python
  Python 2.6.5 (r265:79063, Apr 16 2010, 13:09:56)
  [GCC 4.4.3] on linux2
  Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
  >>> import MySQLdb
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  ImportError: No module named MySQLdb
  >>>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ahh these problem... invest some time in [virtualenv](http://www.virtualenv.org/en/latest/index.html#what-it-does) for python.  It will pay off =)

Answer (score 1):

All,

I got this resolved by the following, in my /etc/bash.bashrc i was importing a pythonpath as /opt/s/
Where django and my site resided.When i removed the following from the pythonpath the import MySQLdb worked..Hope this post will help somebody..

Answer (score 0):

I would check the Python PATH and make a manual build of MySQLDB download. Download the installation files from this source forge site.

Answer (score 0):

The package information shows you what's going on (ubuntu 12.04):

```
apt-cache show python-mysqldb

[...]
Provides: python2.7-mysqldb
Depends: python2.7, [...]
Python-Version: 2.7
[...]
```

This package is for python 2.7 - so it's not installed for 2.6. execute `python2.7` in a shell and try the import again.

(if you have an older ubuntu version, execute the apt-cache command on your machine to check if this is the case in your version as well)

Comment: Provides: python2.6-mysqldb
Depends: python (<< 2.7), python (>= 2.6), python-support (>= 0.90.0), libc6 (>= 2.4), libmysqlclient16 (>= 5.1.21-1)